# How to find the index of certain lists in a list of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have 50 folders containing the same file name but different contents `Data_220_beta_0.1_47.0_53.0ND.csv`. I am skipping certain folders which is mentioned in list `I`. Now, when the code scans all the remaining folders, it looks for values which are different and `X = [x for x in X if min(x) != max(x)]` contains the lists with distinct values. How do I identify the corresponding `i` values which have distinct list elements? The current and expected outputs are presented.

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd

N=50

A=[]
X=[]

I=[8, 11, 19, 37, 40, 42]

for i in range(1,N+1):
    if i in I:
        continue
    
    file_loc =f"C:\\Users\\{i}\\Data_220_beta_0.1_47.0_53.0ND.csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(file_loc)
    A=df["% of Nodes not visited"].to_numpy()
    
    A = [x for x in A if str(x) != 'nan']
    #print(A)
    A = [eval(e) for e in A]
    #print(A)
    
    
    X.append(A)

X = [x for x in X if min(x) != max(x)]
print("i =",i)
```

The current output is

```
i=50
```

The expected output is

```
i=[20,27,37,45,48,50]
```

Comment: It could be me, but I have difficulties understanding your question. Names like `A`, `X`, and `I` are not very descriptive names for your variables. I also do not understand what the `i` is you are searching for. I think more info on your input and expected output would also be helpful!

Comment: I have edited the post. Basically, I want to print all ```i``` corresponding to ```X = [x for x in X if min(x) != max(x)]```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gessing that :

- `X` is a list of lists
- you are trying to find the indices of the values of `X` in `X before it was last reassigned`, which `i` is not, as it can only be the last integer (50) yielded by `range`

Here is a reproducible example:

```py
X = [[18, 43], [29, 2], None, [3, 3], [45], None, None, [52, 66]]

values = [x for x in X if x and min(x) != max(x)]
print(values)  # [[18, 43], [29, 2], [52, 66]]

indices = [X.index(value) for value in values]
print(indices)  # [0, 1, 7]
```

So, in your code, you should:

- replace `continue` by `X.append(None)`
- replace `X = [x for x in X if min(x) != max(x)]` by `values = [x for x in X if x and min(x) != max(x)]`
- before printing, add `indices = [X.index(value) for value in values]`
- replace `print("i =",i)` by `print(f"{indices=}")`, taking advantage of [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings)